# How to pass a ValueType arg to a Method in C# reflection?

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, value-type, methodinfo

My question is that a method requires a `long` type arg and i want to execute it by reflection. However, `MethodInfo` needs a array of object and `long` is a value type, it cannot be cast to object.
How to solve it?

e.g.(just a example)

```
class A
{
  bool IsZero(long a)
  {
    return a == 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: "it cannot be cast to object" - **yes it can**

Comment: Everything is an object. There's not even a cast required. Just create an `Object` array and put whatever you want in it. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=net-6.0#system-reflection-methodbase-invoke(system-object-system-object())) even includes an example that does that with an `int` value. You should NEVER be posting a question here without reading the relevant documentation first.

Comment: if you ask a question, you should always write what you have done (code sample).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parameter must be specified via object[]

```
A myClassAInstance = new A();
MethodInfo mi = myClassAInstance.GetType().GetMethod("IsZero");
long myLong = 23;
var result = (bool)mi.Invoke(myClassAInstance, new object[]{myLong});
```

`myLong` is automatically boxed.

if you have an `int`, you must cast it into `long`

```
long myInt = 11;
var result = (bool)mi.Invoke(myClassAInstance, new object[]{(long)myInt});
```

The number of the elements and the element types in the array must match the number and type of the parameters (signature match)